# database doesn't show the .sql file I created in gedit

Tags: 16.04, mysql

When I create a `.sql` file in `gedit` and save and login to `mysql` on terminal, after the command `show databases` it doesn't show the creates database.

why so?[image]

Comment: Simply creating a text file with SQL statements will not be read by the database server just by itself. What else did you do actually execute the SQL statements? (just as you did `show databases;`)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to load the `sql` file you created, e.g. using?

```
mysql> use DATABASE_NAME;

mysql> source path/to/file.sql;
```

[More info in SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5152921/5088142)